# How to write data to .txt file, without writing it 2 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write some data to a txt file. But everytime it write the data two times and i only wan't it once. Can't figure it out..

The data is collected from the machine and it's the cpu, gpu, harddrive ect. I'm collecting.

Any help is appriciated :)

Below I have attached, which modules I use and how I collect the data in two lists, and write the two lists to the same file.

I tried to do it all in one list, but then I could not collect both GPUs. With the GPUs is the only place where I use a loop to collect the data.

```
import platform                         #   OTHER INFORMATION
from psutil import virtual_memory       #   RAM
import cpuinfo                          #   CPU
from gpuinfo.windows import get_gpus    #   GPU
import psutil                           #   HD

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
content_list = [a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n]


with open(dataFile, "a") as f:
    for item in content_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)


for gpu in get_gpus():
    f = (str("Graphic Card informaion = ") + str(gpu.__dict__))


    gpucontent_list = [f]


    with open(dataFile, "a") as f: 
        for item in gpucontent_list:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

The output of the dataFile looks like this, where everything comes out twice.

```
Machine platform = AMD64
Windows version = 10.0.16299
The platform archictecture = ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
Ramsize = 31.897907257080078 GB
Processor information = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1535M v5 @ 2.90GHz
Total C disk size = 227.00927352905273
Total C disk usage = 217.63811874389648
Free space on C disk = 9.37115478515625
Percent in use on C disk = 95.9
Total D disk size = 465.63573837280273
Total D disk usage = 52.99754333496094
Free space on D disk = 412.6381950378418
Percent in use on D disk = 11.4
Graphic Card informaion = {'name': 'NVIDIA Quadro M2000M', 'total_memory': 4095, 'device_id': 'VideoController1'}
Graphic Card informaion = {'name': 'Intel(R) HD Graphics P530', 'total_memory': 1024, 'device_id': 'VideoController2'}
Machine platform = AMD64
Windows version = 10.0.16299
The platform archictecture = ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
Ramsize = 31.897907257080078 GB
Processor information = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1535M v5 @ 2.90GHz
Total C disk size = 227.00927352905273
Total C disk usage = 217.63818359375
Free space on C disk = 9.371089935302734
Percent in use on C disk = 95.9
Total D disk size = 465.63573837280273
Total D disk usage = 52.99754333496094
Free space on D disk = 412.6381950378418
Percent in use on D disk = 11.4
Graphic Card informaion = {'name': 'NVIDIA Quadro M2000M', 'total_memory': 4095, 'device_id': 'VideoController1'}
Graphic Card informaion = {'name': 'Intel(R) HD Graphics P530', 'total_memory': 1024, 'device_id': 'VideoController2'}
```

And the whole code lookes like this:

```
import platform                         #   OTHER INFORMATION
from psutil import virtual_memory       #   RAM
import cpuinfo                          #   CPU
from gpuinfo.windows import get_gpus    #   GPU
import psutil

dataFile = "pcinfo.txt"

machInfo = platform.machine()
versInfo = platform.version()
platArcInfo = platform.architecture()

# Gather Ram information
mem = virtual_memory()
RamVar = mem.total  # total physical memory available

# Gather the processor informaiton
cpuInfo = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand']

# Gather HD information
obj_DiskC = psutil.disk_usage('C:/')
obj_DiskD = psutil.disk_usage('D:/')

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


a = (str("Machine platform = ") + machInfo)
b = (str("Windows version = ") + versInfo)
c = (str("The platform archictecture = ") + str(platArcInfo))

d = (str("Ramsize = ") + str(RamVar / (1024.0 ** 3)) + str(" GB"))

e = (str("Processor information = ") + cpuInfo)

# C - drive
g = (str("Total C disk size = ")+ str(obj_DiskC.total / (1024.0 ** 3)))
h = (str("Total C disk usage = ") + str(obj_DiskC.used / (1024.0 ** 3)))
i = (str("Free space on C disk = ") + str(obj_DiskC.free / (1024.0 ** 3)))
j = (str("Percent in use on C disk = ") + str(obj_DiskC.percent))
# D - drive
k = (str("Total D disk size = ")+ str(obj_DiskD.total / (1024.0 ** 3)))
l = (str("Total D disk usage = ") + str(obj_DiskD.used / (1024.0 ** 3)))
m = (str("Free space on D disk = ") + str(obj_DiskD.free / (1024.0 ** 3)))
n = (str("Percent in use on D disk = ") + str(obj_DiskD.percent))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
content_list = [a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n]


with open(dataFile, "a") as f: # Append the list data entry to the txt file
    for item in content_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)


for gpu in get_gpus():
    f = (str("Graphic Card informaion = ") + str(gpu.__dict__))


    gpucontent_list = [f]


    with open(dataFile, "a") as f: # Append the list data entry to the txt file
        for item in gpucontent_list:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Could you provide the output too? The contents of dataFile.

Comment: @Alichino Here you go :) I attached both the whole output from the text file and the whole code.

Comment: Did you check whether the file was empty before you ran your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the file in "a" mode:

```
with open(dataFile, "a") as f:
```

You're opening the file in append-mode, which means any new writes will be written to the end of the file instead of replacing the content of the file.

You'd want to open your file in "w" mode, which will truncate the existing content, and keep the same file object open for the rest of the program, or use append mode only for subsequent reopens.

```
with open(dataFile, "w") as f:
    for item in content_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)

    for gpu in get_gpus():
        for item in gpucontent_list:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Your right! That worked for me. Thats way it came out twice